# Using Regular Expressions to remove query strings in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create something that will search Column A1 for query strings from URLs (example: ?other_ ), then remove them by using regular expressions. I have figured out what kind of regular expression to use within the 'Find and Replace' section on Google Sheets, but am unsure how to write it.

Regular expression: `\?(.*)`

Please let me know where I should start with this.

Comment: Please provide some screen shot or share your sheet. Provide the string and desire result

Comment: @Rocky In column A1 of my sheet, we have several results that include query strings, like the following:

/?login=1
/?login=`

We would like to setup a script within Google App script to run and remove these query strings.

Answer (score 2):

Don't need regular expressions to remove query strings.

```
function removeQueryStrings() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vs=rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    let idx=r[0].indexOf('?');
    if(idx!=-1) {
      sh.getRange(i+1,1).setValue(r[0].slice(0,idx));
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to implement it in Google Sheet. But you can use the following regex to get the entire query string:

Regex: `/\?.*$/`

Example in JS:

```js
const regex= /\?.*$/

console.log("example.com/home?utf_medium=browser".replace(regex, "")) // Result: example.com/home

console.log("example.com/post?utf_medium=browser&key=value".replace(regex, "")) // Result: example.com/post
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
function myFunction() {
  //Use Spreadsheet app to select this current spreadsheet, then this current sheet
  let sheetToScan = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0]; 
  //Edit this to be the range you want
  const rangeToScan = 'A1:A5' 
  //load the range
  let range = sheetToScan.getRange(rangeToScan)
  //This expression copys the range's values to a 2D array.
  let cellValuesArray = range.getValues(); 
  //Edit this to be the regex you want
  const myRegex  = /\?.*$/; 
  console.log(cellValuesArray); 
  // 2 layer for loop for 2 dimensional range selection
  for (const row in cellValuesArray) { 
    for (const cell in cellValuesArray[row]) {
      // Convert cell value from an Object to a String
      let stringToSearch = String(cellValuesArray[row][cell]) 
      //IF matches regex
      if (myRegex.test(stringToSearch)) { 
        console.log(cellValuesArray[row][cell]); 
        //replace regex with nothing (delete matched text)
        let replacedWithString = stringToSearch.replace(myRegex, ''); 
        // Set cell value in array to updated string
        cellValuesArray[row][cell] = replacedWithString 
        console.log('Found a Match!!: "', stringToSearch, '" replaced with: "', replacedWithString, '"'); 
      }
    }  
  }
  console.log(cellValuesArray);
  //Set new values with replacements in Spreadsheet
  range.setValues(cellValuesArray); 
}
```

I tested it. Let me know if you have any questions.